# Vim extension coc producing errors after fresh install?

Tags: neovim

I installed the latest branch of `coc` but have been having trouble using it.

For some reason, whenever I enter Insert mode, this error keeps flashing:

```
[coc.nvim] error:     at NeovimClient.emitNotification (/Users/carlosgrijalva/.vim/plugged/coc.nvim/build/index.js:1
```

I also attempted to install certain extensions like `coc-tsserver` and got the following error:

```
[coc.nvim] Error on install coc-tsserver: Error: coc-tsserver 1.6.3 requires coc.nvim >= >=0.0.79, please update coc
.nvim.
```

Not sure what's going on since i'm using the latest release. Below is my `.vimrc`:

```
" PLUGINS
" ===================================
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
Plug 'morhetz/gruvbox'
Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim', {'branch': 'release'}
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
Plug 'junegunn/fzf', { 'do': { -> fzf#install()} }
Plug 'junegunn/fzf.vim'
call plug#end()

" VIM General
" ===================================
set nocompatible
syntax on
set showmode " Shows mode at bottom of window
set relativenumber " Relative number line
set showmatch " Show matching brackets.
set smartcase " Do smart case matching
set smartindent " Do smart indenting
set incsearch " Incremental search
nnoremap <Leader><space> :noh<Enter>
set number " Show line numbers
set noswapfile " Disables creating swap files
set undodir=~/.vim/undodir
set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
let g:gruvbox_contrast_dark='hard'
set termguicolors
colorscheme gruvbox
set background=dark

imap jj <Esc>
let mapleader=","
```

Comment: Probably you'll find better help on [vi](https://vi.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker and/or dedicated support channels.

Answer (score 4):

You're not using the latest coc.nvim release, try to delete `~/.vim/plugged/coc.nvim` and install again.

Comment: If you are using Plugged, as your answer indicates, you might as well just do `:PlugUpgrade`.